# Why scale pixels between -1 and 1 sample-wise in the preprocess step for image classification

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, classification

In the preprocess_input() function found at the link below, the pixels are scaled between -1 and 1. I have seen this used elsewhere as well. What is the reason for scaling between -1 and 1 as opposed to 0 and 1. I was under impression that common ranges for pixels where between 0-255 or if normalized 0-1.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py

Answer (score 0):

The normalization between -1 and 1 aims to making the data has a mean of 0 and std_dev of 1. (i.e. Normal distribution). Also the choice of the activation function used in the network determines the kind of normalization especially when using batch normalization.

For example if **sigmoid** was used and the normalization is done between 0 and 1, then all the negative values obtained from the network (multiplying weights with inputs and then adding biases) will be mapped to zero. (that leads to more vanishing gradients during backpropagation)

Whereas with **tanh** and normalization between -1 and 1, those negative values will be mapped to corresponding negative values between 0 and -1.

**tanh** usually is the activation function used in Convolutional Networks and GANs and is preferred to Sigmoid.

"Tanh. The tanh non-linearity is shown on the image above on the right. It squashes a real-valued number to the range [-1, 1]. Like the sigmoid neuron, its activations saturate, but unlike the sigmoid neuron its output is zero-centered. Therefore, in practice the tanh non-linearity is always preferred to the sigmoid nonlinearity." from the infamous Andrej Karpathy Course [cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1)

Comment: Adding comments like this in your own answer doesn't make much sense; edit & update your post instead.